# How to backup MySQL databases when the MySQL server is off?

Tags: backup, mysql, mysql5

My MySQL server does not start, as according to the guides I found over the internet, the best solution is to re-install MySQL server (with `apt-get purge`). However, this process will delete my databases too.

How can I take a backup from my `InnoDB` databases when the MySQL server is off?

I normally use `mysqldump` for backing up, but it needs the MySQL server to be on and running.

Answer (score 0):

you could do *apt-get remove* instead, and additionally remove config files in /etc/mysql. Also, apt-get might ask you if you really want to purge databases, but that depends on your distribution and version.

But, to answer your question, to backup mysql, you should simply backup all files in it's database, including ib_data* files for InnoDB. Default location in Debian for example is /var/lib/mysql, so you could do:

> tar zcf /root/mysql-backup-2014-08-24.tgz /var/lib/mysql

do verify that you have valid copy before destroying the original database...

Comment: you mean copying `ibdata1` to the new installation would work?

Comment: yes, ibdata *and* all other files and subdirectories. It will work always for same version, and usually for all newer versions (although it is recommended if you need to upgrade mysql to first restore files to the same version, and then do upgrade with your distribution upgrade process, which will take care of possible extra maintenance that needs/should be done). But downgrading to older version is problematic (it might work if versions are close, but it could break too).